# Django - Commands and context dictionaries

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I´m trying to get a context_dictionary from specific urls to use in a django command. Code without the command returns the model with a slug and details to a site, let´s suppose it is localhost/event/mainevent/.

Once I want to get the context dictionary used for that site,how do I get it in my command? 
My code so far is the following:

> Commands/MyCommand.py

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        #Get context processor here
        self.stdout.write(event.title)
```

> Models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

> Views.py

```
def details(request, event_title_slug):
   context_dict = {}
   try:
       event = Event.objects.get(slug=event_title_slug)
       context_dict['event_title'] = event.title
       context_dict['event'] = event
   except Event.DoesNotExist:
       pass
   return render(request, 'event_details.html', context_dict)
```

> Urls.py

```
url(r'^event/(?P<event_title_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.details, name='details')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by context dictionary here. The context in a view is for rendering a template; you don't want to do that in your command. And in any case you don't have a URL in the command, so there is no relationship to the view.

Instead you need to pass an argument, say the slug, to your command, and use that to get the event to delete. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) has an example that does almost exactly what you want.